# Открытие больших файлов JSON на Mac os?

Tags: json, macos

Чем можно открыть на просмотр файлы JSON которые весят более 10-30mb?

Пробовал sublime, atom, visual studio code, textEdit, xCode. Все эти редакторы виснут и ничего не могут сделать. Есть ли возможность на mac os открыть файлы для редактирования JSON большого размера?

Вот похожий файл весом 250mb
https://yadi.sk/d/FlRofG4nQVz2Eg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а просто открыть в браузере пробовали ?

Comment: И sublime не справился? прямо удивлен. Может дело в самом файле или в компьютере... прямо заинтриговали, пойду искать json на 30мб

Comment: sublime хуже всех виснет. Намертво. Комп нормальный core i9 64gb памяти 1TB ssd. Еле еле работает textEdit встроенный в саму систему на нем еще получается.

Comment: Толи картинке раньше не было, толи не обратил внимания. Но на картинке у Вас не 10-30Мб, там почти 400Мб

Comment: А есть возможность этот файл (или подобный с "левыми" данными) куда-нибудь скинуть, хочу у себя проверить?

Comment: Добавил файл. На винде стандартный блокнот отлично его открывает и еще моментально находит в нем нужную строку. То есть проблема в самих программах и программистах под mac. В поддержке мне так и сказали что пиши разработчикам это не наши проблемы, система ведь не зависает.

Comment: В общем перепробовал разные программы платные/бесплатные. Все при загрузке файла брали 13,8% от процессора, а памяти от 500мб до 4Гб, дисковая активность плюс минус как обычно. Ждал по 3 минуты, но ни одна программа так и не открыла файл. Комп не нагревался, вентиляторами не шурстил. И только в PhpStorm файл открылся моментально, но в режиме только чтение (с подписью, что это из-за размера файла). Такое ощущение, что это все-таки на уровне системы что-то, потому что затрагиваемые ресурсы компьютера ну очень похожи и примерное поведение, зависание программы одинаково после определенного времени

Comment: http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/ открыл файл моментально и позволил редактировать. без подсветки синтаксиса. BBedit открыл файл за секунд 20, но на любое действие зависал уже на более долгое время

Comment: @manking после исследований добавил свой ответ (в секцию ответов) про программу HexFiend. Есть еще пара идей, но этот редактор моментально все делает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HexFiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) - моментально открывает, мотает туда сюда по файлу и редактирует. В настройках убираем показывать HEX данные и работаем как с текстовым файлом.

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решилась использованием виртуальной windows 10 на mac os. Там стандартный блокнот моментально все открыл и позволил даже скролить всё. Так что ответ такой что на Mac os так сделать не получится система довольно слабая для профессиональной разработки и не справляется с серьезными задачами, из-за которых сам макбук сильно греется (боюсь что сломается при попытке открывать текстовые файлы). :(

Comment: Вот и неправда. На самом деле там есть вполне себе обычный и нормальный textedit, не хуже блокнота, а также терминал, в котором есть вполне легковесные решения типа vim.

Comment: Я уже писал, что textedit и vim зависают намертво. Проверьте сами и не пишите недостоверную информацию.